# Semantic - Unexpected character '@' with Webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, semantic-ui

> Error Terminal

```
ERROR in ./~/semantic-ui-css/semantic.css
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected character '@' (11:0)
```

> Error Console chrome

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "semantic-ui-css/semantic.css"
```

I found the error it's in this line `import 'semantic-ui-css/semantic.css';` so i search for this kind of error, i just installed `url-loader` and keeps the same error, here's my webpack config

```
module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.js$/, loader: 'babel-loader', exclude: /node_modules/ },
            { test: /\.jsx$/, loader: 'babel-loader', exclude: /node_modules/ },
            {
                test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/,     <--- this delete a lot of errors with semantic, but wont work with "Unexpected character '@'"
                loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000'
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'eslint-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loaders: [
                    'style-loader?sourceMap',
                    'css-loader?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[path]___[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
                ],
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loaders: [
                    'style-loader',
                    'css-loader?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[path]___[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]',
                    'resolve-url-loader',
                    'sass-loader'
                ],
                exclude: /node_modules/
            }
        ]
    }
```

so, how should i fix this issue? i think it's something with `import 'semantic-ui-css/semantic.css';` for something that i dont get it yet, maybe because it dosnt have `import (this section) from 'semantic-ui-css/semantic.css';`

Answer (score 0):

change this:

```
{ 
  test: /\.css$/, 
  loaders: [ 'style-loader?sourceMap', 'css-loader?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[path]___[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]' ],
  exclude: /node_modules/ 
},
```

to this:

```
{
  test: /\.css$/,
  loaders: [ 'style-loader?sourceMap', 'css-loader?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[path]___[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]' ]
}
```

In other words... remove the `exclude`.

Another option is to not change as mentioned above... And you probably dont want to assume css modules for all node_modules. I think this way is better... So, instead add an additional rule:

```
{
  test: /\.css$/,
  include: path.resolve('node_modules'),
  use: [
    {
      loader: 'style-loader',
      options: {
        sourceMap: true
      }
    }, {
      loader: 'css-loader',
      options: {
        sourceMap: true
      }
    }
  }]
}`
```